# Is there a way to compress a base64 string?

Tags: java, compression

I have a base64 string which is too long (it encodes a pdf file).
I get this string from a remote service so I can't do anything about that.

I'd like to further compress/decompress it so that the traffic from the remote service to my local service is lower.

Is it possible?

Comment: Use [Ascii85](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii85)?

Comment: If "I can't do anything about that" means you can't modify the remote service then no, you can't lower the bandwidth between the remote and yourself.

Comment: Send it with gzip or deflate streams which Java supports out-of-the-box. If the remote service is out of your hands but is a HTTP server, you can ask it to do gzip and/or deflate with the `Content-Encoding` header.

Answer (score -1):

It depends...

- What do you wanna do with it? Store it or send it?
- Do you need it to be super web safe, or you can even use ascii command codes? (If you need to send it you may need it to be web safe, which means your character options is kinda limited, and that kinda excludes binary compression algorythms.)
- How much time and knowledge you have to come up with a decent compression algorythm...

Using binary compression makes it difficult to view it on the screen, or even iterate through as character array as you normally would with strings. Non binary compression is kinda poor solution in this case, cause the characters appear in random order, so harder to find repeating substrings...

The easiest way I see is by turning into binary values, and discarding the extra 2 bits and padding, as base 64 actually fits into 6 bits not 8, so you can store 4 characters in 3 bytes, but then you need to convert them back to characters in order to view them on the screen... It can not be sent either cause some of the raw data may be interpreted as ascii control characters or non web safe ones, etc. but you can store it in binary files, and thus save space, and load it faster if that's the goal.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).